# "some Protocol" causes type to not conform to protocol

Tags: swift, combine

I don't understand why this doesn't compile. It does if I remove the `where` restriction from the `P` type.

```
import Combine

protocol Foo {
    associatedtype P: Publisher where P.Output == Int
    var publisher: P { get }
}

struct Bar: Foo {
    var publisher: some Publisher {
        Just(1)
    }
}
```

The error says that `Type 'Bar' does not conform to protocol 'Foo'`. I guess it's because `publisher` return type is not just any `some Publisher`. But in SwiftUI, the `View` uses a similar approach, just that it doesn't have restrictions over the `View` type.

Is there any way I can make this code to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't compile is because `some Publisher` declares an opaque type, but the protocol requires that the type must be "see-through".

`some Publisher` is "opaque" in the sense that callers cannot see exactly what type the property actually is, and can only know that it conforms to `Publisher`. This directly contradicts with the protocol requirement that `P.Output` has to be `Int`. **To check `P.Output` is `Int`, you have to "see through" `some Publisher`**, but you can't.

Since the compiler can't check the publisher's `Output`, it can't check whether your type really conforms to the protocol or not. Therefore it chooses the "safe route" concludes that your type does not conform to the protocol.

I think you should use the `AnyPublisher` type eraser:

```
var publisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    Just(1).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

---

SwiftUI's `View` protocol does not have this problem because it does not require `Body` to be "see-through". It just requires that `Body` is a conformer of `View`, which `some View`, by definition, is.

Comment: Really clear answer. I was trying to avoid using `AnyPublisher` but I understand now why it cannot be done. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I don't know where the bad habit of trying to use `some Publisher` in these situations comes from. Outside of SwiftUI I can't think of a reason to use `some`.