# Returning the Concrete Type Based on Protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I have following code:

```
protocol Vehicle {
    func start()
}

class Car: Vehicle {
    func start() {
        print("Start car")
    }
}

class MotorCycle: Vehicle {
    func start() {
        print("Start MotorCycle")
    }
}

let vehicles: [Vehicle] = [Car(), MotorCycle()]

func get<T: Vehicle>() -> some Vehicle {
    let result = vehicles.first {
        $0 === T.self
    }
    return result!
}

// so I should be able to do this! 
let car = get<Car>().start()
```

Inside the `get` function I want to go iterate through vehicles and return the concrete type of the Vehicle, which is either `Car` or `MotorCycle`. Finally, I want to call `start` on the returned type. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: `Car` does not have a function called `startCar`. It does have `start`. `start` does not return anything, so you can't assign it to `car`. For the last line, did you mean `get<Car>().start()`?

Comment: Yes I mean start. updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `get` should be written:

```
func get<T: Vehicle>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
    vehicles.first(where: { $0 is T }) as? T
}
```

- There might not be any `T`s in `vehicles`, so we should return an *optional* `T`.
- For the implementation, you should use `is` to check the type in the `first(where:)` closure. Then, cast to `T`.
- You can't directly pass type arguments like `<Car>` to a function in Swift. Type arguments must always be inferred. So I used a formal parameter `type` to help Swift infer what `T` is.

Caller:

```
get(Car.self)?.start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think this can also be done by using Opaque types in Swift or should it be done using Opaque types.

Comment: @johndoe Oh I didn't noticed you changed it to opaque types in the edit. I don't think using opaque types is suitable at all. Since the method asks the caller 'what type do you want?", it is natural to return whatever type the caller is requesting. Opaque types is used to _hide_ the actual return type. Here, the caller knows what they are getting. There's no point in hiding.

Comment: @johndoe This reminds me of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821754/some-protocol-causes-type-to-not-conform-to-protocol/63821841?noredirect=1#comment112858146_63821841) that I received yesterday. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare an instance value with a type like this: `$0 === T.self`. You can use `$0 is T` instead.

And, when calling a generic function, you cannot explicitly specialize a generic function. The type has to be inferred, like @Sweeper said.